# Why is the character following this macro-defining macro gobbled up?

Tags: macros, tex-core

I have the following plain Tex code:

```
\def\xx{ABC}
\def\temp #1 {\def\tempii{#1}}
\temp\xx a b c
\tempii\tempii
```

I expect to see the following output:
    `a b c ABCABC`

But I actually see this:
    `b c ABCaABCa`

Why is the 'a' snatched into the definition of \tempii?

Comment: The reasoning here is not limited to plain so I've retagged: I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm still thinking as to why it is, but this revision (embracing `\xx`) gives you what you want.

I think the answer is that, in the usage `\temp\xx a b c`, the space after `\xx` is from the TeX parser's view, not a space at all, but merely signifies the end of the macro name `\xx`.  For example, if you just put `\xx A` on a line by itself, you will see that it prints out as `ABCA` without a space.  Thus, the parser sucks in the trailing "A" as being connected to `\xx`.  One could also use `\temp\xx{} a b c`, as a way to tell the parser that the space is a separator, and not just the next character following `\xx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\xx{ABC}
\def\temp #1 {\def\tempii{#1}}
\temp{\xx} a b c
\tempii\tempii
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're surely right, and I feel like saying "Ah, of course."  But now I don't understand why `\temp\xx\ a b c` doesn't give the desired result.  It's like the escaped space is ignored by the pattern matcher.  (Also, you converted the code from plain Tex to Latex, but that didn't matter.)

Comment: @dedded I'm sure one of the erudite ones will chime in with a fully rational answer, but (again speculation because I'm out of my depth) I'm thinking that in an effort to get the argument to `\temp`, it expands until it comes to something that can't expand.  In both cases (what I describe in my answer and what you describe in your comment), that would be the letter "a".

Comment: @dedded `\temp\xx\ a b` doesn't have a space token after `\xx`, it has a control symbol ``\ `` (remember: TeX is all about tokens). You could do `\def\firstofone#1{#1}` then `\firstofone{\temp\xx} a b c`.

Comment: @dedded the `\ ` token isn't ignored it just doesn't match a space just as `\a` would not delimit an argument delimited by `a`.

Comment: Accepting this answer because with D. Carlisle's comment it most completely clears my misunderstanding, but I suspect egreg's detailed explanation is the more generally useful one.

Comment: @dedded  Thanks.  I agree with you completely that egreg's answers are inevitably more thorough and accurate than mine.

Answer (score 11):

For clarity I'll denote space tokens by `•`, as they are very important in the discussion; spaces in the following code samples should be ignored.

The parameter text of `\temp` is

```
#1•
```

while the replacement text is

```
\def\tempii{#1}
```

Your call of `\temp` is

```
\temp\xx a•b•c•\tempii\tempii
```

Notice that after `\xx` there's a space just for delimiting the macro; it is *not* a space token: it's nothing, because TeX always ignores spaces following control *words* (not control *symbols*). The space after `c` comes from the end-of-line in your code.

The tokens following `\temp` are scanned (without expansion) to find a match with the parameter text, where the argument is delimited by a space, so `#1` ends being `\xx a` and the next state of the input stream is

```
\def\tempii{\xx a}b•c•\tempii\tempii
```

Now TeX performs the definition and removes it from the input stream:

```
b•c•\tempii\tempii
```

and the part `b•c•` is passed to the typesetting stage. After the expansion of the two copies of `\tempii`, this is equivalent to having typed

```
b•c•\xx a\xx a
```

or

```
b•c•ABCaABCa
```

which is exactly what you got.

If you had used `\?` instead of `\xx` the last two lines would have been converted into

```
\temp\?•a•b•c•\tempii\tempii
```

because `\?` is a control symbol and TeX doesn't ignore spaces after them. In this case the result would be

```
a•b•c•ABCABC
```

Note that

```
\expandafter\temp\xx a•b•c
\tempii\tempii
```

would produce the same result, because after the action of `\expandafter` TeX would be presented with

```
\temp ABCa•b•c
```

(same convention for spaces as before, of course). You'd get the same result as with `\?` instead of `\xx` with

```
\expandafter\temp\expandafter\xx\space a•b•c
```

because then TeX would be presented with

```
\temp\xx•a•b•c
```

Indeed spaces are ignored after control words only during the tokenization process.